# Add a unique data attribute to react dom elements using webpack for development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am looking to add a certain data attribute to all my DOM elements on react for example

```
 <input
            hidden={this.props.hidden}
            // auto attribute
            data-testid={'uniqueAttribute45454'}
          />
```

I want this `data-testid` followed by a unique string for all my DOM elements (input, dropdown, checkbox) . I want to do this via webpack so that I can segregate my webpack dev and webpack prod (I want this on dev only). Any webpack plugins available for this? I have been researching for quite a while but haven't found anything.

Comment: To be clear, you want any DOM elements rendered with a React component (`let MyComponent = props => <div>test</div>`) to receive unique `data-testid` attributes? What is your ultimate purpose here?

Comment: Yes, the ultimate purpose is to enable a better e2e testing (cypress) right now, all styles are inlined. Having a unique attribute to all the DOM elements if possible would make my life so much easier.

Comment: Well, since these DOM elements are going to be created by JS, I doubt webpack will be able to do what you're asking, but maybe a custom Babel transform that processes your JSX could do the job. Alternatively, you could wrap all of your low level elements with components (`<Input/>`) that add the attribute themselves.

Comment: Any babel plugins you have in mind? I want to avoid code changes as much as I can.

Comment: Not having an easy time finding plugins to process raw JSX. `react-dom` *might* have a place to process the elements React mounts.

Comment: Hi @Dhiraj, have you found a solution to this problem yet? If so; do you mind sharing it?

Comment: Not exactly as we would have liked @scaryguy but we ended up using react css modules with styleName  attribute , this enables to use specific selectors for e2e testing https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a Babel plugin that you can use:

https://github.com/shawnxusy/babel-plugin-react-generate-property

Readme says:

> A plugin to automatically generate and add properties (for example data attributes) for all JSX open tags, especially styled components (Emotion, Styled Components, etc)

Exactly what I was looking for!